# Extract count value from Kusto query in Python

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm struggling with extracting the count value from a Kusto Query, in the Kusto Python SDK.
I know the query works from the UI console, but whenever I try to do so in Python, it fails.
Here's my query:

```py
query = f"""
{table}
| where isempty({column})
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2h)
| count
    """
query_result = kusto_client.execute(KUSTO_DATABASE, query)
query_result = dataframe_from_result_table(query_result[0])['Count']
```

I get `KeyError` exceptions and despite debugging the object I don't how to extract the count value.

Is there a better way to do so?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The Kusto SDK returns **multiple result sets**, which includes the result set(s) of your query, in addition to the query properties and the execution statistics.

What you want is the **primary_results**

```
query_result = dataframe_from_result_table(query_result.primary_results[0])['Count']
```

[Using SDKs --> Python --> Explore data in DataFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/python-query-data#explore-data-in-dataframe)

---

Here is a full working demo based on the publicly available cluster, Help.

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table

cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net"

db = "Samples"

query = """
StormEvents
| count
"""

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_interactive_login(cluster)
client = KustoClient(kcsb)

response = client.execute(db, query)

print(dataframe_from_result_table(response.primary_results[0])["Count"])
```